# How to pass javascript variable to graphql query?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, graphql-js

I have a super simple GraphQl query, but im having trouble to make the query dynamic based on input. Lets say you will get a string in javascript that you want to pass along to the query, how is it done? Take example below, how would i replace the hardcoded string of "3111" on the Sku field in the product but instead inserting the value from the variable myString? I am just getting errors when i try to pass it along.

```
let myString = "3111"

`query getProductBySku {
        site {
          product(sku: "3111") {
            id
            entityId
            name
            sku
          }
        }
      }`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look here: https://graphql.org/graphql-js/passing-arguments/

In your case scenario:

```
var query = `query getProductBySku($sku: String) {
        site {
          product(sku: $sku) {
            id
            entityId
            name
            sku
          }
        }
      }
`;

fetch('/graphql', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    query,
    variables: { "3111" }, // this refers to SKU
  })
})
  .then(r => r.json())
  .then(data => console.log('data returned:', data));
```

---

Basically other than creating a query that allows argument to pass, you need a POST request with the body setup to accomodate the inputs which are expected to be fulfilled

Comment: should it not be `variables: { sku : "3111" }` ?

Comment: @andymccullough yea, I thought so. If you open the link the official doc it reports you can use positional arguments though. Without the need to declare the specific parameter you're referring to.

Comment: There is no need for `variables` object in the body as arg to `stringify`. Just pass the var to `query` with `${sku}`. It works because of the backticks.